# Parse date in ZF2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm having a problem.

I'm using ZF2, and getting an error here.

```
$inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
    'name' => 'dataInicial',
    'required' => true,
    'validators' => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'NotEmpty',
            'options' => array(
                'messages' => array(
                    \Zend\Validator\NotEmpty::IS_EMPTY => 'A data do feriado deve ser preenchida.'
                )
            )
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'callback',
            'options' => array(
                'messages' => array(
                    \Zend\Validator\Callback::INVALID_CALLBACK => 'Data no formato inválido.'
                ),
                'callback' => function ($value, $context = array()) {
                        $dataInicial = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $value);
                        return $dataInicial->format('d/m/Y');
                }
            )
        )
    )
)));
```

I'm getting this error:

```php
DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (25/12/2014) at position 0 (2): Unexpected character
```

When I execute the same code in pure php, without zend, it works ok.

```php
echo DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '25/12/2014')->format('d/m/Y');
```

Maybe someone knows what's causing the error? Sorry for my english

Comment: Your English is OK. ;-)

Comment: `\Zend\Debug\Debug::dump($value);` and check it really is `string(10) "25/12/2014"` as you were expecting

Comment: @Crisp Yes, i already did this. Like expected, this echo string(10) "25/12/2014"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know what kind of database backend and relationship mapping but the issue is related to how the date is being stored I imagine, most likely like: Y/m/d

If you saving and getting this error then it's because you need the date in this format. If you are hydrating you may also need a date strategy to deal with hydration like:

```php
// InputFilter.php
class yourInputFilter()
{

    $hydrator->getHydrator()->addStrategy('my_attribute', new MyDateHydrationStrategy()); 

    $this->add( array(
        'name' => 'registration_starts', 
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\DateTime', 
        'options' => array ( 
            'format'=>'Y/m/d',                 
        )
    )); 
}
```

```php
// YourForm.php
class YourForm Extends ....
{
    $dateTime = new Element\DateTime('youDate');
    $dateTime->setLabel('Date')
             ->setOptions(array(
                'format' => 'Y-m-d\TH:iP'
    ));
}
```

```php
// Strategy.php
class myDateTimeStrategy implements StrategyInterface
{
    public function hydrate($value)
    {
        if (is_string($value)) {
            $value = new DateTime($value);
        }

        // Could return in a different format, probably can't though because of when you need to edit
        // return $value->format("m-d-Y")

        return $value;
    }
}
```

You will also need to change js settings if you using a datetime widget picker:

Which will be something like:

```js
$('.datepicker').datepicker('format', 'yyyy/mm/dd');
```

Depending on which one you using.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but still not working. Me and my co-workers already spent a lot of time in this. I'm not using any widget picker.

Here is my form
http://pastebin.com/YWsGb7Tw

my model
http://pastebin.com/PN416Hdm

and here de Strategy class
http://pastebin.com/yXb273Ht

My sprint ends today and I really need this working :(

Comment: So what happened when you changed all instances of 'd/m/Y' to 'Y/m/d' and used format "2014/02/07" as string? Also can you post your controller code for the add action I guess and schema for the model code.

Comment: Re the model schema was just wondering if it is setup as timestamp or date or datetime or what :)

Comment: Infact I'm pretty sure you have the field set to Time in the Schema not Date

Comment: "Failed to parse time string" normally says "Failed to parse date string" when using a field with type of date

Comment: Will still need to be going into the db like "Y/m/d" though. Unless doctrine does something with it. I use Propel so dunno the exact ins and outs of doctrine

Comment: Thanks again. Here is the controller http://pastebin.com/jYi3qebk and in the model is already set as date. You can see here http://i.imgur.com/YJxflVG.png

Comment: Did changing the date format work, assume this is fixed since u accepted answer? If not have more ideas :)

Comment: Doctrine already have an Strategy to work with dates. So I need to create a new class extending DoctrineHydrator and overwrite the method handleTypeConversions, and here is the code if someone else need. ObjectHydrator class http://pastebin.com/DE9p87Th and the DateTimeStrategy http://pastebin.com/5vUWPyV3 Thankyou for all, Jon Day. And sorry for bad english